# How do I make the simplest viewmodel work?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im trying to understand how to use a viewmodel to bind data to a wpf window but cannot find any simple examples or explanations on how that is achieved.

This is what I have so far:

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Info = "Infoo";
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PeopleApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PeopleApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="212,137,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Info}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Why does the textbox not show "Infoo"? What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I've changed the field in the ViewModel to a property, but how do I connect the ViewModel to actual data?

Comment: WPF data binding works with public properties only. Your `public string Info` is a field, not a property. Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, that makes sense! But how do I connect the properites in the ViewModel to the properties of an object that holds a property with a string that actually contains data?

Comment: {Binding ObjectA.Info}

Comment: _"...cannot find..."_ - I would suggest looking on the internet rather than under your desk. This a well documented pattern....a 30 second search gave me this http://nkdagility.com/mvvm-for-dummies/

Comment: You can also use a MVVM Framework to ease the databinding. It requires Setup at the beginning but the using later is pretty easy. For example, this blog Shows how it works with Caliburn.Micro http://hintdesk.com/c-wpf-mvvm-databinding-2014/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mistakes in your code:**

- You need to have property on the VM not the public field.
- you need to set the value for the property of VM instance before assigning it to the `DataContext` of `MainWindow`

This should work.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="PeopleApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PeopleApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>       
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="212,137,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Info}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {         
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel() { Info = "Infoo" };
    }    
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Info { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I didn't get that I actually had to have an instance of the ViewModel and make sure that instance gets the info from the right place. Now MVVM makes a little bit more sense!

Answer (score -1):

Your View(Window) and ViewModel(class) are various parts of application. You should use `DataContext` property to interact between View and ViewModel and create properties, not fields like you've done in your case. For example:

**View:**

```
<Grid>        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayTime}" />        
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private string displayTime=DateTime.Now.ToString;
    public string DisplayTime
    {
        get { return displayTime; }
        set { displayTime = value; }
    }
}
```

There are many approaches to set DataContext:

**The first approach. In view:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

**The second approach. You should override OnStartUp() method of App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
     protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MainWindow app = new MainWindow();
            ProductViewModel context = new ProductViewModel();
            app.DataContext = context;
            app.Show();
     }
}
```

**The third approach. In constructor of Windows:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     public MainWindow()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
          DataContext=new MainWindowViewModel();
     }
}
```

**The fourth approach.** You can set DataContext through DependencyInjection by UnityContainer. But DependencyInjection, Prism and UnityContainer are other questions and goes from this scope of the question. Just for example:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
{ 
    unityContainer.RegisterType<object, ItemControl>("ModuleAUpper");
    unityContainer.RegisterType<IViewModelItemControl, ViewModelItemControl>();
    unityContainer.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ItemControl>();
}
```

Comment: @downvoter it is really interesting. Why did you downvote?

Comment: He asked for a simplest viewmodel to work.  Anyway, your answer is interesting.  Also, I haven't downvoted.

Comment: i'm not the downvoter, but i can explain to you why it's downvoted because i did it in the past - you're providing an answer to a person who is too lazy to google and asks a question which has been answered hundreds of times - and thus promoting the behavior of producing useless content and offloading homework to someone else