# How bind ObservableCollection to ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have class

```
public class Clip
{
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Duration { get; set; }
}
```

And `ObservableCollection`

```
public ObservableCollection<Clip> _clipsFound;
public ObservableCollection<Clip> collection
{
    get { return _clipsFound; }
    set
    {
        _clipsFound = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

`OnPropertyChanged()` is invoked when I do

```
_clipsFound = collection
```

I want binding data from collection to ListBox with three columns: ID, Name, Duration

Initialize

```
ID = id;
collection = new ObservableCollection<Clip>();
_clipsFound = collection;
_clipsFound.Clear();

ICollection<Clip> ClipF = await Service.GetClips(ID);
ICollection<Clip> Clipcol = ClipF;
collection = new ObservableCollection<Clip>(Clipcol);
```

I try do this, but it doesn't work

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="ui:Clip">

                <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                                                           Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                           Foreground="#FF4F4F4F"
                                                           FontSize="12"
                                                           Margin="55 0 0 0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                                           Margin="0 0 45 0"
                                                           Text="{Binding Duration}"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                           FontSize="11"
                                                           Foreground="#FF4F4F4F"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please can you be more specific than "it doesn't work". What doesn't work? Do you get nothing? Binding errors in the debugger's output window? Something else?

Comment: is your "Duration" working? if yes - is your collection public? the way you've written it in your question suggests that it is a private property and if i remember correctly, this could cause Problems.

Comment: I've just noticed you are binding to "Title", but there's no "Title" property on your `Clip` class.

Comment: "Title" is the Title of the xaml-window

Comment: Also, you didn't show how you initialize your `collection`. It may be empty for all we know.

Comment: @MarcelB - not in this case. The binding is on the DataTemplate so it's a binding to a property on the objects in the ItemsSource - in this case `Clip`.

Comment: @ChrisF, collection chenged, OnPropertyChanged() invoking, but listbox stay empty

Comment: @str_str `collection` is private, isn't it?

Comment: @Valentin, no, collection public

Comment: also, I tried to realize it by another way and it works

Comment: Should it not be like : `OnPropertyChanged("collection");`  to tell wich property has changed

Comment: @Joh, yes, problem in this

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send data from viewmodel to view without setting `DataContext`. `DataContext` is like channel or bridge between `ViewModel` and `View`.

This code sets `DataContext`:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <vm:MainWindowViewModel />        
</Window.DataContext>
```

Let's see work example:

**Your ViewModel:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
   publicMainWindowViewModel
   {
       LoadData();
   }
   private void LoadData()
   {
      _clipsFound=new ObservableCollection<Clip>();
      for(int startIndex=0; startIndex<10; startIndex++)
      {
          collection.Add(new Clip(){ID=startIndex, Name="Bob", Duration=startIndex++});
      }
   }

   public ObservableCollection<Clip> _clipsFound;
   public ObservableCollection<Clip> collection
     {
         get
         {
             return _clipsFound;
         }
         set
         {
             _clipsFound = value;      
         }
     }
}
```

**Your XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSelectedItemsWpfApplication.MainWindow"
    ...The code omitted for the brevity...
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataGridSelectedItemsWpfApplication.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="550" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
   <vm:MainWindowViewModel />        
</Window.DataContext>
<ListBox Grid.Row="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="ui:Clip">    
           <Grid>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="11" Margin="2" Foreground="#FF4F4F4F"/>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"          TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Foreground="#FF4F4F4F" FontSize="12"/>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Duration}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" Foreground="#FF4F4F4F"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
</ListBox>
</Window>
```

[There are many ways to set DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599702/how-do-i-make-the-simplest-viewmodel-work/35600220#35600220).